# Moving turtles to specific coordinates of other agents in NetLogo

Tags: coordinates, netlogo

I have individuals (turtles) and I have households (turtles with fixed xy)
I have a variable **address** stored at households. I have a number of a family attached to individuals. The households has the same number.
How can I ATTACH or MOVE the individuals to their corresponding household?
I tried something like:

```
ask individuals
   [ if family = [family-place] of household
      [
        move-to [address] of household 
      ]                        
   ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`move-to household` should do it.

Comment: It did not work. I have different numbers of households. I have to have a way to indicate 'move-to' which household. I thought 'the household that has the same number stored in individuals. The erro indicated is 'household expect 1 input, a number' Asking the question in a different way. How do I apply a variable of the household to the individual? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is a slow monday morning, here is how I would do it. 
I assume **familiy-number** to be the name of the common number in both moving and sessile turtles. I would use **let** to create a local variable that only works within the procedure. (See the procedure **go-home** for this)

```
breed [walkers walker] 
breed [houses house]

houses-own [family-number] 
walkers-own [family-number] 


to setup 
  clear-all 
  set-default-shape houses "house"
  create-houses 10 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set family-number random 10000
  ]  
  reset-ticks
end 

to leave-home 
  ask houses [
    hatch-walkers 1 [
      set family-number [family-number] of myself 
      set color [color] of myself 
      set heading random 360 
      fd 1 
    ]
  ]
end 

to go
  ask walkers [
    rt random 120 
    lt random 120   
    fd 1
  ]
  tick 
end 

to go-home 
  ask walkers [
    let family-place one-of houses with [family-number = [family-number] of myself]
    move-to family-place  
    fd 1 ;; walker will step away one step so we can see him. 
  ]
end
```

Just copy it into NetLogo, make a button for each procedure and play. Works best if in the order

```
setup  
leave-home
go  
go-home
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also good. Appreciate it. Thanks. (I would vote up, but I have to have 15 points ;(

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding your question, so I've having to guess at what you want, but with the help of your comment on Bryan's answer, maybe I've guessed right?

```
ask individuals [
  move-to one-of households with [address = [family-place] of myself]
]
```

if this seems confusing because of the `myself`, you could also write it as:

```
ask individuals [
  let f family-place
  move-to one-of households with [address = f]
]
```